# C# NModbus Network Slave - getting master count

Tags: c#

Using NModbus (https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus) and I'm looking for a way to determine the number of masters connected to a network slave.

Looking at the NModbus  code, it appears that ModbusTcpSlaveNetwork.Masters.Count might do the trick.  Unfortunately ModbusTcpSlaveNetwork is an internal class of the library.

Comment: you should be able to get the count - you can have a look at this unit test where they to assert to master count - https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus/blob/master/NModbus.IntegrationTests/NModbusTcpSlaveFixture.cs

Comment: The IntegrationTest project appears to be out of date and not used.  Though the code is download from GIT, its not referenced by the NModbus solution.  The Integration tests also reference classes that are now internal to the NModbus Library.   

When "rquackenbush" create the NModbus fork from NModbus4 he put in place  bunch of interfaces and hide a lot of the implementation classes.   I think in the process, access to the master counter of the concrete class is now hidden to the outside world.